# Paypal Payments Pro & IPN Responses : Redundant or Necessary?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, paypal, magento-enterprise

We're using Paypal Payments Pro to process Credit Cards and Paypal Express Transactions. In our development environment, IPN responses must have been disabled or not enabled but now that we're live, they are working and creating and additional history transactions when we capture funds.

The first `comment history` says:
Captured amount of $XX.XX online. Transaction ID: "8YX040ABC2920X".

The second `comment history` says:
IPN "Completed". Registered notification about captured amount of $XX.XX. Transaction ID: "8YX040ABC2920X".

I wouldn't think this is a big deal except when the IPN notification comes, it resets the order status back to `Processing Credit Card` if the order was set to something like `Pre-Shipping`.

**Is IPN nessesary when you're using the Payments Pro API?** (should I disable it?)

**Can IPN responses be handled differently?** (Maybe by elevating instead of reverting the order status?)

**What is best practice?**

Comment: You can non-intuitively disable Paypal IPN.. you have to goto Profile -> IPN Settings.. (1) Enable IPN [Tip: use http://anydomain.com/] (2) then you can disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Paypal Payment Pro API, the IPN updates are unnecessary for Charging transactions. You can disable them (by enabling them first - see above). However, if you wish to take advantage of other useful IPN updates like "chargeback" you will have to work with events.